# How to Open a Firefox Private Browser Window with VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, firefox

I would like to somehow get my program to multiple firefox browser windows (hidden) and go to a certain url. Is this possible? Can someone help point me in the direction I need to go?

I read that people see hidden browsers as malicious, but really I just want to open 20 tabs of it and not have it cluttering the users desktop.